# stop url changing when user comments

Tags: comments

When a comment is posted on a blog post the url of the page changes. Is there a way to prevent this from happening. 
I need to show my post in a popup and it is replying on the url, when a comment is added the url changes and it leaves the popup.
How can I keep the post in the popup also when a user posts a comment?

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful for you....
https://crunchify.com/how-to-remove-url-website-field-from-wordpress-comment-form/
https://justlearnwp.com/remove-website-url-wordpress-comment/

Comment: thanks for your help, but I was referring to the page URL, not the URL comment form field.